# Trying to edit the registry in Windows with a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, registry

I am supporting a few offices across the country running Windows XP. They are stand alone, no Windows Server or Active Directory, anything like that. I just switched them over to Google Apps, and in the process replaced Windows Live Messenger with Google Talk. I really want to stop Windows Live from being used, the platform sends so much spam and seems to have a lot of holes. I have tested making a registry edit to key

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\DisallowRun
```

adding a string value `msnmsgr.exe` set to `1`. I did it manually on one machine, and it worked, under both profiles, it wouldn't start Messenger. After my success, I wrote a .REG file thusly:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\DisallowRun]
"msnmsgr.exe"="1"
```

And a batch file, run from the same directory, written like this:

```
@ECHO off

REGEDIT.EXE /S msn.reg
```

It seems to write to the registry, but Live is starting. No idea what's happening. Seems this could have gone either way between Serverfault and here, but I went here since the Administration part seems resolved yet the little programming involved isn't working out.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looks to me like you have the Registry value name and data swapped. According to the [kb article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/323525), the REG_SZ value(s) should be named numerically starting with "1", and the included data would be the executable name ("msnmsgr.exe"). Thus, your .REG file should look like this:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\DisallowRun]
"1"="msnmsgr.exe"
```

Also, I would recommend that you use the [REG.EXE](http://www.petri.co.il/reg_command_in_windows_xp.htm) program for simple edits like this, rather than importing a .REG file. For the change you wanted, your REG.EXE command would look like this:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\DisallowRun" /v "1" /t REG_SZ /d "msnmsgr.exe" /f
```

Comment: And I would place that line in a batch file?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The `reg add ...` command should work directly on the command-line or in a batch script.

Comment: Hi, I tried and it did work. My question is how to disable the prompt confirming to add registry?

Comment: There will be no prompt if you use the /f switch.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742162(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Export the registry key that you manually added and compare the .reg file to the one you imported via regedit.

Comment: I am sorry, I meant HKEY_CURRENT_USER.

Comment: (Edited original question for HKCU.)

Comment: The files are exactly the same