# Editing registry files with a batch script

Tags: batch-file, scripting, registry

I want to make the following registry changes:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontDPI]
"LogPixels"=dword:00000060

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Hardware Profiles\0000\Software\Fonts]
"LogPixels"=dword:00000060

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Hardware Profiles\0001\Software\Fonts]
"LogPixels"=dword:00000060

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Hardware Profiles\Current\Software\Fonts]
"LogPixels"=dword:00000060

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontDPI]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]
"LogPixels"=dword:00000060
```

But I want them to be made via a batch script. How might I go about doing this? I tried to save this all as a .reg file and simply import the file using my script, but I got an error that it couldn't open the file.

Comment: Why not import this with regedit ?

Comment: .reg files should start with `REGEDIT4` or `Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trying to edit the registry in Windows with a batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961790/trying-to-edit-the-registry-in-windows-with-a-batch-file)

Comment: @Marged when I try to import it with regedit, I get an error that I can't open the file. I have added "REGEDIT4" at the top of my .reg file, but stil no luck.

Comment: Could this be because the secondlast line contains no value ? Shos us your batch and try to run the same command from the command line

Comment: What's the text coding of your file?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get what I needed done using reg add:

```
::Restore DPI to 100% (CDB Text Scaling Issue Fix)
::Call "%~dp0\Restore 100% DPI Fix.bat" (Doesn't seem to be working right)
@Echo OFF
cls

reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontDPI" /v "LogPixels" /t REG_DWORD /d "00000060" /f
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Hardware Profiles\0000\Software\Fonts" /v "LogPixels" /t REG_DWORD /d "00000060" /f
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Hardware Profiles\0001\Software\Fonts" /v "LogPixels" /t REG_DWORD /d "00000060" /f
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Hardware Profiles\Current\Software\Fonts" /v "LogPixels" /t REG_DWORD /d "00000060" /f
reg DELETE "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontDPI" /f
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop" /v "LogPixels" /t REG_DWORD /d "00000060" /f
```